# Can I integrate EmberJS with Joomla 3.x module or component?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, joomla3.0

Is there any possibility to integrate **EmberJS with Joomla 3.x**?

I tried to do in a simple application, but it doesn't seem to work. If anyone did this, please provide guideline and example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Here is a guide to integrate emberjs in wordpress. You can follow the same route to integrate it into your joomla module or component

https://isotope11.com/blog/ember-dot-js-wordpress-integration